# What does MCMC do during burn-in period?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

I am studying mcmc and I am wondering what mcmc does during burn-in period. And also what is the difference during burning period and after the burn-in period?

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov chains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MCMC relies on building a Markov chain whose stationary distribution is a joint distribution you wish to sample from.

But you don't start at the stationary distribution, you start at some initial value (in multivariate space). It may take some time for the process to "wash out" the initial conditions. Under suitable conditions the approach to the stationary distribution is geometric (though the parameter may be close to 1, in which case the approach may be fairly slow).

Once the effect of the initial condition has essentially dissipated, you should be sampling from the same distribution no matter the starting point. You should then be able to regard the samples as a series of correlated observations from the target joint distribution.

With a Gibbs sampler (for example), it can be useful to have many starting points; if the samples you get from those don't appear to be all from the same distribution, either you needed longer burn in or you have an issue with the design of your sampler for that particular problem (e.g. it might be getting stuck in different modes with very low inter-mode transition rate, and the sampling scheme may require modification to ensure that you move between them).

Comment: This might be actually another question, if allowed, I'd like to ask if MCMC needs cumulative probability distributions at all. Does MCMC need cumulative probability distribution at all? or it just builds a stationary Markov Chain?

Comment: @ChangheeKang: this is another unrelated question. Please provide background and motivation in this new question.